# How to unlock my IP on Centos firewall?

Tags: centos, firewall

I have a VPS with Centos and with firewall that I used to configure by Lxadmin. Now I don't have Lxadmin control panel and can't go to change it by web interface. How to discover what firewall I have on my machine and where is the config with blocked IP so I can remove mine?

Comment: Your own IP is blocked on the server?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS, the default location for iptables rules are `/etc/syconfig/iptables`. If you want to whitelist your work IP, add this right after the `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` line:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s <YOUR_WORK_IP> -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for iptables by just typing the command

```
iptables
```

EDIT: ... can you get to a shell?

Comment: I'm currently trying to whitelist my work IP so I can get to my server at home. Going thru the /etc/hosts.allow, and my moblock whitelist.
Just some other things that could block you.